# Database model about libraries

Tags: sql-server, mysql, database-design, postgresql-9.3

I need to make database model about libraries. In that model I'm tracking more libraries and every library has it's own moderators. Every moderator can make categories of the books and than add books in categories (note: another library doesnt need to have same as categories of books as library where that moderator is working, every other library can have different categories of books .. ).

[image]

This picture represents how did I make it. But something is missing, think this is not good solution. I have also another tought.. To link  tables "book" and "category_book" in N:M and than link "book" and "libraries" which from I can get everything I need. But, think it's also not the best solution because every library will in that moment has same categories of books.

Am I missing something or? Haven't met with this kind of problem yet so if you could help me I will be grateful

Whole design ...Note: it's not over, I can't move further beacuse of this problem[image]

Comment: Am I right in thinking a `Book` can only be in _one_ `Category` (per library)?  If so, why not have a `Library_Category` table, and then the `Category_Book` table (which can then link directly to `Book` as you mention)

Comment: I have Library_categ table.. But, you are trying to say that book in the first place need a category which I will make with **Category_Book** and than when moderator makes a category in **Library_Category** he will be able to update the same table with  _book_ which is in the same _category_(defined in table **Category_Book**) as he is trying to update?

Comment: Search for "Libraries" on this [page](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) - they have a whole section on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Description**

I'm synthesising that these are your constraints:

1. One `Book` can be in MANY `Category`'s, but only in **ONE** `Category` per `Library`.
2. Each `Library` can have *ZERO or more* `Category`'s, which they do not have to "*share*" with other `Library`'s.

**Solution**

This should all be achievable via the following structure (ignoring your *wider* solution space with users, borrowing, etc):

[image: Categorised Library Books ER Diagram]

---

<sub>**Note:**  The link between `library_has_category` and `book_in_library_category` is a composite key of the *library* **AND** *category* keys together.</sub>

Comment: Yes, I think this is a pretty much what i have been looking for. Thank you
I will post my finally solution so you can correct me if I am missing something out :)

Comment: No problem!  If this fully *answers* your question, then don't forget to **Accept** the answer.  Otherwise you can keep editing/clarifying until it is 100% solved.

Comment: Nah, I think it's ok, you did it well. Really appriciate this, thank you mate :)

Answer (score 1):

From what you're saying it looks like your business rules are as follow:

1. A library can have one or more categories
2. A category can have 0 or many books
3. A book must belong to 1 or more category

If that's what your business rules look like, then do the following:

Library (1:n) -------- (n:n)library_category (n:n) -------- (1:n)category

Then for books:

category (1:n) ------(n:n)category_book (n:n) --------- (1:n) book

That way libraries will have different amount of categories and a book will belong to different categories.

You don't need a link between book and library because you can get that through library_category/category_book.

Comment: Thank You,  think I will able to make something from Your and @Tersosauros answer :)